# Parse.com cloud code - afterSave running twice

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have some afterSave code running on parse.com and it **appears** yo be running it twice.

Here is the cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Review", function(request) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("ReviewAverage");
    query.equalTo("vendor", request.object.get("vendor"));
    query.find({ 
        success: function(average) {
            if ( average.length === 1 ){
                average = average[0];
                average.increment( "numReviews" );
                var currentTotal = average.get("totalScore") + request.object.get("rating");
                var currentAverage = currentTotal / average.get("numReviews");
                average.set("totalScore",  currentTotal ) ;
                average.set("averageScore", currentAverage) ;
                average.save();
            } else {
                var average = new Parse.Object("ReviewAverage");
                average.set("vendor", request.object.get("vendor"));
                average.set("numReviews", 1);
                average.set("totalScore", request.object.get("rating"));
                average.set("averageScore", request.object.get("rating"));
                average.save();
            }
        },
        error: function(e){
            console.error("Error updating averages: " + e);
        }
    });
});
```

I have my review table, and also, rather than calculating review averages for the same item on the fly (as parse doesnt support group by type functionality) I have another table that just keeps track of the running average for an item (keyed by vendor).

I have noticed some discrepancies between the numReviews for a given vendor in the ReviewAverage column against the actual number of Reviews that exist for the same vendo.

Looking in the logs, I am seeing stuff like the following:

```
I2014-11-14T08:08:45.818Z] v13: after_save triggered for Review for user dA73DS733H
  Input: {"author":{"className":"_User","objectId":"dA73DS733H","__type":"Pointer"},"createdAt":"2014-11-14T08:08:45.815Z","objectId":"j1wfWfQabv","rating":7,"review":"Lacking pigs in blankets and would have benefitted from more crunchy stuffing but otherwise good - the healthy Christmas option.","updatedAt":"2014-11-14T08:08:45.815Z","vendor":"Pret - Christmas veggie lunch","ACL":{"dA73DS733H":{"read":true,"write":true},"*":{"read":true}}}
  Result: Success
I2014-11-14T08:08:46.278Z] v13: after_save triggered for Review for user dA73DS733H
  Input: {"author":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"dA73DS733H"},"rating":7,"review":"Lacking pigs in blankets and would have benefitted from more crunchy stuffing but otherwise good - the healthy Christmas option.","vendor":"Pret - Christmas veggie lunch","createdAt":"2014-11-14T08:08:45.815Z","updatedAt":"2014-11-14T08:08:46.260Z","objectId":"j1wfWfQabv","ACL":{"*":{"read":true},"dA73DS733H":{"read":true,"write":true}}}
  Result: Success
```

I have seen some people having issues, because they are re-saving in the afterSave function - but my save is only ever to the ReviewAverage object, so shouldn't be any reason to trigger again?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having issues with afterSave too, where creating a new object(type X) with a pointer to an existing object(type Y) is causing afterSave on object(type Y) to trigger.

So if I save both objects it seems like afterSave was triggered twice.

Are any of the columns in your ReviewAverage class of type Pointer?

Comment: any solution how not to trigger afterSave on pointer save? Tnx

Comment: @DaNLtR I havent been able to fix it and just used a different approach... But I read on the parse developer mailing that this issue was fixed in the latest parse release. I havent tested it myself.